# Array of Classes declaration and manipulation

Tags: c++, arrays, string, class

I was hoping somebody could help explain the correct way to initialise an array of classes and how I can add elements to the array?

My code currently looks like this:

```
class Person
{
private:
    string surname;
    string forename;
    int age;
public:
    Person() { suraname, forename, age; }
    void getSurname();
    void getForename();
    void getAge();
};
```

Ultimately the program will read lines from a file into the array to populate it, but firstly I just want to be able to manually add so that I can see that it's working.

Because there are going to be multiple people, does my array need to be 2D?

Eventually we will use "getSurname()" to loop through all the surnames in the array and print them to console.

In my head I know that adding to the array is going to look something like this (although I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it)

```
int main()
{ 
    std::string Person[2][3] = {
      { "Smith", "John", "21" }, 
      { "Farr", "Michael", "35" }
    };
}
```

If anyone could help explain / give guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Your constructor doesn't look right.

Comment: What do you think `Person() { suraname, forename, age; }` does? Did you mean to pass parameters there?

Comment: `Because there are going to be multiple people, does my array need to be 2D` So you don't even know what an array is?

Comment: I knew Person() was my constructor, although I've always been slightly confused by them. I'm new to Object Orientation so I'm trying to get my head around it.

Comment: So create a single Person and print getSurname().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one step after the other...

fix this (because is not correct):

```
public:
    Person() { suraname, forename, age; }
```

it must be something like

```
public:
    Person(suraname, forename, age):suraname(suraname), forename(forename), age(age) { }
```

then rename this to something more appropriated

```
std::string Person[2][3]
```

like

```
std::string ArrayOFFieldsOfPerson[2][3] = ...
```

---

now you can start with something more easy to handle like

```
std::string testSurname{"XoceSurname"};
std::string testForename{"XoceForename"};
std::string testAge{"18"};
```

and then do

```
int testAgeInt = std::stoi(testAge);
Person somePerson{testSurname, testForename, testAgeInt };
```

after that you have properly constructed an instance of a person, for an array  you can do something like:

```
Person somePersonArray[k];
```

and then use a loop to populate the array

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much for the explanation.

Comment: I'm following your second "easier" example, and I'm just wondering how you print the line 'Person somePerson{testSurname, testForename, testAgeInt };' to console?